# Trim last two lines of an attributed string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

How do I remove the last two lines of this NSAttributedString?

```
NSString *exampleString = @"line 1\nline 2\nline 3\nline 4"
NSAttributedString *as = [NSAttributedString alloc] int];
[as setString:exampleString];
[self removeLastTwoLinesOfAttributedString:as];
NSLog(@"%@",as);

-(void)removeLastTwoLinesOfAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)string {
   //some code here
}
```

I'd like to end up with @"line 1\nline 2" in this example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Swift you can do this, if you're using Objective-C you should look at the other answers.

You can drop the last two lines of a `String` like this

```
string.components(separatedBy: "\n").dropLast(2).joined(separator: "\n")
```

To do it to an attributed string just access the `string` property, remove the last two lines, and create an attributed string with the trimmed string and all the same attributes.

Comment: Please provide the Objective-C version, per the tags in the question.

Comment: @koen whoops, I missed that. I added a disclaimer since there already are other ObjC answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this :

```
 -(NSAttributedString *) removeLastTwoLinesOfAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *aString) {
   NSRange range = [aString.string rangeOfString:@"\n" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
   range = [aString.string rangeOfString:@"\n" options:NSBackwardsSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, range.location)];
   return [aString attributedSubstringFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, range.location)];
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSString *exampleString = @"line 1\nline 2\nline 3\nline 4";
    NSAttributedString *as = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:exampleString];
    as = [self removeLastTwoLinesOfAttributedString:as];
    NSLog(@"%@",as);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
line 1
line 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest as the best solution:

```
-(NSAttributedString *)removeLastTwoLinesOfAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)aString {

    if (aString.length == 0) {
        return aString
    }

    NSString *string = [aString string];

    unsigned numberOfLines, index, stringLength = [string length];
    NSRange rangeOfLastTwoLines = NSMakeRange(aString.length - 1, 0);

    for (index = stringLength-1, numberOfLines = 0; index >= 0 && numberOfLines < 2; numberOfLines++) {
        NSRange rangeOfLine = [string lineRangeForRange:NSMakeRange(index, 0)];
        rangeOfLastTwoLines = NSUnionRange(rangeOfLastTwoLines, rangeOfLine);
        index -= rangeOfLine.length;
    }

    return [aString attributedSubstringFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, rangeOfLastTwoLines.location)];
}
```

This has the benefit of working with any newline character not just "\n" and it uses the preferred by Apple method for detecting lines see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/CountLines.html)

Also it will not break if the last two lines are less than 2